# I get "a foreign key constraint fails" error when attempting to join two classes/tables

Tags: sql, database, grails, grails-orm

I have these classes, abbreviated for practical reasons:

```
class CV {
  Date dateCreated
  static hasMany=[proposals: Proposal]
}  

class Proposal {
  String name
  Date date_started
  static hasMany = [CVs: CV]
  static belongsTo = CV
}
```

Grails creates tables for both these classes, and a third class named "cv_proposals" joining them. So far, so good. I have data in both the CV and the Proposal tables, they both have autoincremented "id" values. All good.

in Oracle MySQL Workbench, I try to manually add values to the joining table to get some dummy data to work with. I get an error message with this trace:

> ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
>   (`cvreg_utv`.`cv_proposals`, CONSTRAINT `FK17D946F55677A672` FOREIGN KEY (`cv_id`) REFERENCES `cv` (`id`))

I made sure both the tables had several lines of data in them, and that I could edit both of them separately.

After trying dropping and recreating the table, altering the classes back and forth, I'm kind of convinced that this operation somehow has to be done through a running Grails application. So I write this script in a controller and run it:

```
def g = CV.get(1)
Proposal proposal = g.addToProposals(new Proposal(
name: "SavingTest", 
date_started: new Date())).save()
```

I still get the same error, though. Is this not the right way to define a proposal that is connected to a certain CV? Am I wrong in using a many-to-many connection here somehow?

Edit: adding the schema-create script for the joining table

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TABLE `cv_proposals` (  
  `proposal_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  
  `cv_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,    
  PRIMARY KEY (`cv_id`,`proposal_id`),  
  KEY `FK17D946F55677A672` (`cv_id`),  
  KEY `FK17D946F5F7217832` (`proposal_id`),  
  CONSTRAINT `FK17D946F5F7217832` FOREIGN KEY (`proposal_id`) REFERENCES `proposal` (`id`),  
  CONSTRAINT `FK17D946F55677A672` FOREIGN KEY (`cv_id`) REFERENCES `cv` (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

And the CV table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cv` (  
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  
  `version_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `FKC734A9AB992` (`user_id`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

And the Proposal table:

```
CREATE TABLE `proposal` (  
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  
  `date_ended` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `date_started` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

This is the insert script I tried to run:

```
INSERT INTO `cvreg_utv`.`cv_proposals` (`proposal_id`, `cv_id`) 
VALUES ('1', '1');
```

Comment: Maybe is the `belongsTo` of the Proposal that's failing?

Comment: How so? I don't get any error messages. Also, why would that affect whether or not mySQL would give me permission to edit table data manually? It seems that's where the error lies, somehow Grails creates table restrictions that are causing conflicts.

Comment: "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" - look at the foreign keys of your table, it seems that you inserted a cv_id that don't exists.

Comment: yeah, I can not figure out why it fails. I've made sure that both the CV and Proposal tables have a line with the id value 1, and I've tried with other values as well. Curiously, I get the same error message if I try to use a value that's *not* included in the other tables.

I've also tried dropping the tables and let Grails create them again, still does not solve the problem.

Comment: Use the command `schema-export` and post here the create of the tables.

Comment: edited main post. Was this what you wanted to see?

Comment: Can you post the create of the proposal and cv? And also the insert's that you tried to do directly in the database. Only with full information you will get a better answer :-)

Comment: Will do, thanks a lot for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You crated the tables manually? It's interesting that cv table is using MyISAM engine and the others uses InnoDB.

I think you want to use InnoDB to all your tables, since this engine is transactional. In my test, I also was unable to create the `cv_proposals` table until I changed the cv creation:

```
 CREATE TABLE cv (
    id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    version bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    version_name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    date_created datetime NOT NULL,
    last_updated datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY FKC734A9AB992 (user_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101
```

After that, the insert's worked smoothly.

Comment: Grails created the tables automagically from my classes, I pulled the create scripts from oracle mysql workbench. Thanks a lot for the input, I'll see if I can make it work in the morning!

Comment: Yup, that was our problem right there. I got a script from another guy working on this with dummy data, where the tables were changed to MyISAM, while the new tables made from my new classes were created as InnoDB by grails by default. Thanks for your help in locating the problem!